# ReadLine is not working inside the workflowstep

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, workflow

I am creating steps of registration in .NETCore Console application.Inside the step , i am using the `Console.ReadLine` to read the input from console application. But it terminated abruptly.

```
public class SendRequestStep : StepBody
{       
    public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.Write("IsChanged?");
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (result)
        {
            case "Yes":
            {

            }
            case "No":
            {

            }
        }
        return ExecutionResult.Next();
     }
 }
```

Anyone faced the above issue while using workflow core?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That will not work because the workflow run on a background thread. Maybe you can create a step that waits for external event (`ExecutionResult.WaitForEvent(eventName, eventKey, effectiveDate)`), then you can send whatever you collect (using `Console.Readline()` or anything else) through `Host.PublishEvent(eventName, eventKey, data)`.

On your Step do something like this:

```
public override ExecutionResult OnRun(IStepExecutionContext context)
{
    if (!context.ExecutionPointer.EventPublished)
    {
        // do more stuff here...

        return ExecutionResult.WaitForEvent(eventName, eventKey, effectiveDate);
    }

    // Get the sent data from `context.ExecutionPointer.EventData`
    Result = context.ExecutionPointer.EventData;

    return ExecutionResult.Next();
}
```